# MeteorJS: Properly use wrapAsync on vzaar api with callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, callback

## **Problem:**

I am trying to return something(uploaded video ID) async from a API to my code when finished uploading a video. This is because it returns `undefined`. This is a working code from the API docs from [vzaar](https://github.com/vzaar/vzaar-api-nodejs).

```
api.uploadAndProcessVideo(videopath,
  function (statusCode, data) {
    return data.id;
  }, {
    title: "my video",
    profile: 3
});
```

But when I try to wrap this in a async function, I fail. **How should this be properly done?**

I tried the following without luck:

```
function getvideoid(videopath, callback) {

    api.uploadAndProcessVideo(videopath, callback, {
        title: "my video?",
        profile: 3
    });
};

var wrapped = Meteor.wrapAsync(getvideoid);

return wrapped(videopath);
```

EDIT: Came a bit closer with the code underneath, the correct ID are now displaying in the server console, but still returns `undefined` on client. I must be close. **Someone know?**

```
    function getvideoid(videopath, callback) {

        api.uploadAndProcessVideo(videopath, callback, {
            title: "my video",
            profile: 3
        });

    };

    function status (statusCode, data) {
        console.log(data.id);
        return data.id;
    }

    var wrapped = Meteor.wrapAsync(getvideoid);

    return wrapped(videopath, status);
```

Answer (score 0):

api.uploadAndProcessVideo is an asynchronous call and you cannot return a value from an async callback. In this case you should handle API response within the callback which you pass into the function. For example:

```
api.uploadAndProcessVideo(path, function(statusCode, data) {
 if (statusCode === 200) {
   var videoId = data.id;
   doSomething(videoId);
 }
})
```